# Error converting IP number to IP address from ip2location database?

Tags: powershell, geolocation, ip, geoip, ip2location

I have downloaded ip2location database in csv format and reading 1st column data and converting IP number into IP address using below code as suggested in ip2location FAQ.

**Sample CSV Data:**

[image]

```
function Convert-NumbetToIP
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$number
    )

    try
    {    
        $w = [int]($number/16777216)%256
        $x = [int]($number/65536)%256
        $y = [int]($number/256)%256
        $z = [int]$number%256

        $ipAddress = "$w.$x.$y.$z"
        Write-Host "Actual IP Address - $ipAddress"

        Write-Host "Returning IP Address"
        return $ipAddress
    }
    catch
    {
        throw $_
    }
}

Convert-NumbetToIP -number 2147483648
```

But get below error **Cannot convert value "2147483648" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."**

Can someone help me to to get the correct IP address also please let me know what type of data is in 2nd column.

Comment: Changing all `[int]` to `[int64]` will solve the error. Not sure if it will do what you expect tho

Comment: There is a module for IP manipulation and conversion: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Indented.Net.IP/6.3.2

Comment: Or set `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][uint32]$number` and remove all the casts to `[int]`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon works fine but can you explain what is 2nd column mean in csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by changing the [int] to [int64]

```
function Convert-NumbetToIP
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$number
    )

    try
    {    
        $w = [int64]($number/16777216)%256
        $x = [int64]($number/65536)%256
        $y = [int64]($number/256)%256
        $z = [int64]$number%256

        $ipAddress = "$w.$x.$y.$z"
        Write-Host "Actual IP Address - $ipAddress"

        Write-Host "Returning IP Address"
        return $ipAddress
    }
    catch
    {
        throw $_
    }
}

Convert-NumbetToIP -number 2147483648
```